# How to make dynamic type Props with Typescript in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i'm making a reactJs application that receives a dynamic list of props from the backend. I'll put this list of props in my redux state to access in my pages:

## example of object:

{
mainTitle: 'Todo list',
actionTitle: 'next',
inputLabel: 'Enter with your name',
}

My question is: Is it possible to create a dynamic type for this object? On my page i need to acess these props with IntelliSense (autocomplete).

Comment: I don't understand. Does this object exist at compile time? Because that would make it not dynamic by definition. If not, then no, it's not possible. Typescript types exist only at compile time.

Comment: You could just accept a type Record<string, string> (or whatever possible value types you have) or a mapped type `type Props = {[key: string]: string (or whatever possible types you have here)}`. But neither will give you autocompletion. That is only possible with types that can be determined at compile time.